# How do I limit Wix bootstrapper bundle installs based on whether it is installed in silent mode?

Tags: wix, installation, conditional-statements, silent

I would like to check whether the UI is in quiet/silent mode or gui mode and then either error or exit installation if the ui is displayed, preferably with a message indicating that this "cannot be run in gui mode"

in WiX 3.11 there is a variable WixBundleUILevel:
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html

but how do I give an error if this value is set to show the UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add to: Bundle wxs

```
xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">

<Bundle .... \>
<bal:Condition Message="reason">WixBundleUILevel=2</bal:Condition>
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense"/>      
<Chain>
```

when calling candle and light, include

```
  -ext (wixfolder)bin\WixBalExtension.dll"
```